How to test a function on a ROS 2 node that requires a static transform to be published?
I want to do some unit testing on a ROS 2 node. On a particular function, the node looks up for a specific transform. If not available, it should throw an exception.
While in other instances I have managed by populating some attributes of the node, I cannot do that for this instance without altering the node's source code.
The ideal would be to programmatically publish the static transform, inside a test_*.py, and then check the function output to assert it is the expected result, but I have been trying and cannot do it.
Any ideas?
I tried to create some ROS 2 nodes on my tests, but I cannot get them to communicate.
The node has a lot of code, but the relevant part is here:

def get_new_transform_coordinates(
    self, mission_x, image_msg, camera_name, image_type
):
    try:
        timestamp = Time.from_msg(image_msg["timestamp"])
        base_link = (
            self.__base_link_frame_id.get_parameter_value().string_value
        )

        if self.check_time_stamp_fresh(timestamp):
            transform = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform(
                base_link, image_msg["frame_id"], timestamp
            )
            pos_x = int(
                transform.transform.translations.x * 1000
                + mission_x * 1000
            )
            pos_y = int(transform.transform.translations.y * -1000)
        else:
            self.get_logger().error(
                f"The image of type {image_type} for camera {camera_name} is too old!"
            )
            pos_x = pos_y = -1
    except TransformException as ex:
        self.get_logger().error(
            f"Could not transform {camera_name} to base_link: {ex}"
        )
        pos_x = pos_y = -1
    return pos_x, pos_y



What does the node's code actually look like? I don't think there is a scenario where you'd actually want to be publishing transforms in a unit tests. Instead mocking out the tf object is most likely the optimal solution.

I have included the function that requires the static transform. That mocking could be a good solution. Could you provide an example, please?

Does it work for topic subscription too?
